# Incompatible pointer type errors

Tags: c

I am working on a project that is using enumeration, structures, and strings and I keep getting an incompatible pointer type error.  I believe it is because my enumeration is an integer type and my string is a character, but I can't figure out how to fix it.  Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum {Clubs,Heats,Diamonds,Spades}Suits_Of_Cards_ENUM;
typedef enum {Ace,Deuce,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,Jack,Queen,King}Rank_Of_Cards_ENUM;

typedef struct
{

Suits_Of_Cards_ENUM suit[4];
Rank_Of_Cards_ENUM rank[13];

}CARDS;


int main(void)
{
    //Declaring Strings
    const char* suit_name[] = {"  Clubs", "  Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades"};
    const char* rank_name[] = {"Ace", "Deuce", "  3", "  4", "  5", "  6", "  7", "  8", "  9", " 10",
                           "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    CARDS deck[52];

    int i;
    int count = 0;
    int num = 1;

    for(i=0; i<=52; i++)
    {
        strcpy(deck[i].suit, suit_name[count]);   //Error is here

        //Assigning the card number
        strcpy(deck[i].rank, rank_name[num - 1]);  //Error is here

        num++;

        //If statement for assigning numbers
        if((i+1)%13==0)
        {
             count++;
             num = 1;
        }//end if

    }//end for

    printf("Before Shuffling:\n\n");

    count = 0;
    for(i=0; i<=52; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s \t", deck[i].rank, deck[i].suit);  //Error is Here
        if(count < 3)
            count++;
        else
        {
            printf("\n");
            count = 0;
        }//end else
    }//end for
    return 0;
}//end main
```

Comment: Enums are not strings, nor are they characters.

Comment: `deck[i].suit = (Suits_Of_Cards_ENUM)count; deck[i].rank = (Rank_Of_Cards_ENUM)(num-1);`.  Also make the definitions in that struct normal values, not arrays.  Since `CARDS` appears to represent a single card, a card has only one suit and one rank.

Comment: Is this to replace the lines I am having errors on?  It seems to bypass my strings now.

Comment: Why do you have arrays in the `CARDS` structure in the first place? Each card just has one suit and rank, which each should just be a single `enum`.

Comment: Do you also expect `int i; strcpy(i, "5");` to work?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a seg fault...

```
CARDS deck[52];

for(i=0; i<=52; i++)
{
    strcpy(deck[i].suit, suit_name[count]);   //Error is here

    //Assigning the card number
    strcpy(deck[i].rank, rank_name[num - 1]);  //Error is here
```

0 <= i <= 52 so i has 53 possible values and if i = 52, deck[i] will overflow...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use strings, then you need to use strings.  As Colonel Thirty Two said, you can't `strcpy` a string into an enum.  Furthermore, I would define a `struct` for a single card, then create an array of those to compose your deck.  Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_CARDS_IN_DECK 52

typedef enum {Clubs=0,Heats,Diamonds,Spades,NUM_SUITS}Suits_Of_Cards_ENUM;
typedef enum {Ace=0,Deuce,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,Jack,Queen,King,NUM_RANKS}Rank_Of_Cards_ENUM;

 struct Card
 {

   Suits_Of_Cards_ENUM suitEnum;
   char strSuit[16];

   Rank_Of_Cards_ENUM rankEnum;
   char strRank[16];

 };

 int main(void)
 {
   int cardIndex;
   struct Card deck[NUM_CARDS_IN_DECK];

   //Declaring Strings
   const char* suit_name[] = {"  Clubs", "  Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades"};
   const char* rank_name[] = {"Ace", "Deuce", "  3", "  4", "  5", "  6", "  7", "  8", "  9", " 10",
                       "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

   for (cardIndex=0; cardIndex<NUM_CARDS_IN_DECK; cardIndex++)
   {
     deck[cardIndex].suitEnum = (Suits_Of_Cards_ENUM)(cardIndex%(int)NUM_SUITS);
     deck[cardIndex].rankEnum = (Rank_Of_Cards_ENUM)(cardIndex%(int)NUM_RANKS);
     strcpy(deck[cardIndex].strSuit, suit_name[cardIndex%(int)NUM_SUITS]);
     strcpy(deck[cardIndex].strRank, rank_name[cardIndex%(int)NUM_RANKS]);
   }

   printf("Before Shuffling:\n\n");

   for(cardIndex=0; cardIndex<NUM_CARDS_IN_DECK; cardIndex++)
   {
     printf("%s %s\n", deck[cardIndex].strRank, deck[cardIndex].strSuit);  //Error is Here
   }//end for
   return 0;
 }
```

An alternative would be to simply write functions to translate the `enum`s into strings instead of including the strings in the card `struct`